# Highcharts won't load form external file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, highcharts, browserify

I have an html file with 3 Highcharts on it. Everything works fine when I have the script inside that file, but when I try to load the highcharts from external file they won't render. My folder structure is like this:

```
src
 ->js/charts.js
   views/index.html
```

I am trying to get charts.js like this:

```
<script src="../js/charts.js"></script>
```

But I get error:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

This is the beginning of my charts.s file:

```
$(function () {
    $.getJSON('https://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename=usdeur.json&callback=?', function (data) {
    var detailChart;

    $(document).ready(function () {

        // create the detail chart1
        function createDetail(masterChart) {

            // prepare the detail chart
            var detailData = [],
                detailStart = data[0][0];

            $.each(masterChart.series[0].data, function () {
                if (this.x >= detailStart) {
                    detailData.push(this.y);
                }
            });
```

I am using Browserify and in app.js I have:

```
 var $ = require('jquery');
 var foundation = require('foundation-sites');
 var motionui = require('motion-ui');
 var charts = require('./charts.js');

 $(document).foundation();
```

Comment: Are you deploying it in any server ?@Marco

Comment: So what URL are you “on” in your browser, for the page that tries to embed this script?

Comment: Try with absolute URL, that means www.domain.com/js/charts.js or localhost/site/js/charts.js if you are on a local environment setup.

Comment: I have tried with it, but it doesn't find a file @Forcefield

Comment: Maybe you blocked access through htaccess to .js files?

Answer (score 0):

IIS -> Authentication -> Anonymous Authentication, select Application pool identity and click OK.

Failing this I would press F12 and view source and check the path of the javascript file in here, but the path looks fine.